# pfSense as IPSec remote access client

Tags: remote-access, ipsec, pfsense, ikev2, vpn-client

I have a pfSense router in a residential environment and need to use IPSec/IKEv2 as a remote access client to a commercial VPN provider. I know the pfSense web UI doesn't support the router being the remote access client, but the underlying FreeBSD OS should. My questions is would setting up the connection in the underlying OS mess up any routing/firewall settings or have interfaces not show up in pfSense? If not, then is [this](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/FreeBSD) the best guide for setting it up on the base OS?

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely mess up the ipsec/vpn configuration set up in the pfSence itself. As about routing/firewall part - doubt it, but still possible. Anyway, the psSense is like a starter FreeBSD pack for newbies, so as soon as you're starting asking questions about the underlying OS it means you're ready for the next level.

There's nothing difficult in FreeBSD configuration comparing to the pfSense. Only that UI is missing.

The example you are referring to is merely an installation example, not configuration one. NAT-T is already in the GENERIC kernel, that one advice is kinda obsolete.